# call a file contains a list of table

Tags: table, ingres

I'm using Ingres Database and I've this procedure that create a text file with a list of tables. How i can call the file into the where condition?

```
select request_num,table_name,temp_table
from tables
where temp_table in ('$/tmp/dba_tablelist')
```

Actually when i run the file is fine, the only problem is that the where condition can't see the list of table, also if the table is just one.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - they are using [Ingres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ingres_%28database%29)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer, I believe, is I don't think you can like that.

I believe you'll have to use the copy() SQL statement to load the file into a temporary table (`DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE session.tables`) and use

```
SELECT temp_table FROM session.tables
```

in the `IN` clause.